# Can't register user using devise and JWT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

Basically, I am trying to do token authentication with devise and JWT in rails. I followed this guide: https://dev.to/dhintz89/devise-and-jwt-in-rails-2mlj

When a make a request using postman to the route I believe should register a user, I get the error defined in the controller: 422 Unprocessable entity "email or password is invalid"

My registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    user = User.new(sign_up_params)

    if user.save
      token = user.generate_jwt
      render json: token.to_json
    else
      render json: { errors: { 'email or password' => ['is invalid'] } }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,

  controllers: {
      registrations: :registrations,
      sessions: :sessions
  }

  root 'homepage#index'
  get '/*path' => 'homepage#index'
end
```

When I run rake routes, I get the following:

```
  new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                        sessions#new
                         user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 sessions#create
                 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                sessions#destroy
                    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
                   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
                        user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                      POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
             cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  registrations#cancel
                new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 registrations#new
               edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    registrations#edit
                    user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         registrations#update
                                      PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         registrations#update
                                      DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         registrations#destroy
                                      POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         registrations#create
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        home#index
```

My request looks like:

http://localhost:4000/users?email=test@gmail.com&password=abc123&password_confirmation=abc123

What am I missing?

Comment: Change your `user.save` to `user.save!` and you will likely get an exception telling you why your user creation is failing.

Comment: @rmlockerd I used this method and found out my create method was not getting the params, so I overrode the sign_up_params and it worked. Can you please tell me why adding the ! threw an exception? I am new to rails. Thanks!

Comment: When ActiveRecord methods like `.save`, `.create`, and `.update` fail validation, they return an object that has `.valid?` set to `false` and error details. The bang equivalent (`.save!`) of each just immediately raises an error. Not necessarily graceful error handling in production, but it's a quick and obvious route to understanding what's going when developing.